# How to solve EF: Potential runtime violation of table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using EF 4 in my web application.

here are my relevant tables:

```
**AppToDomains_V1 **
GroupId   uniqueidentifier
AppGuid   uniqueidentifier

**Apps table**
AppName   nvarchar(50)  
AppGuid   uniqueidentifier  
ClientAppID   nvarchar(50)  
IsDeleted     bit   
CreatedDate   datetime  
UpdatedDate   datetime
```

and my edmx:

http://ge.tt/17n6R2e/v/0?c

I get the following error:

> Error 2   Error 3002: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line
>   1565:Potential runtime violation of table AppToDomains_V1's keys
>   (AppToDomains_V1.AppId, AppToDomains_V1.Domain): Columns
>   (AppToDomains_V1.AppId, AppToDomains_V1.Domain) are mapped to
>   EntitySet AppToDomains_V1's properties (AppToDomains_V1.AppId,
>   AppToDomains_V1.Domain) on the conceptual side but they do not form
>   the EntitySet's key properties (AppToDomains_V1.AppId,
>   AppToDomains_V1.Domain, AppToDomains_V1.IsWhiteListed).
>     D:\MaM\Server\MamAdmin\Dev\Admin
>   1.7\MaMDBEntityFramework\MaMModel.edmx    1566    15  MaMDBEntityFramework

How can I resolve this?

D:\MaM\Server\MamAdmin\Dev\Admin

> 1.7\MaMDBEntityFramework\MaMModel.edmx    1566    15  is:

```
      <EntitySetMapping Name="AppToDomains_V1">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MaMDBModel.AppToDomains_V1">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="AppToDomains_V1">
            <ScalarProperty Name="IsWhiteListed" ColumnName="IsWhiteListed" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Domain" ColumnName="Domain" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="AppId" ColumnName="AppId" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the Domain and IsWhiteListed properties are set as the Entity Key?

Comment: Add a screenshot of your mapping. You will much likely get some answer. Most users here will not go to download your model and open it in VS.

Comment: @RobG Can you please explain what is the Entity Key? is it the primary-key? Anyhow the primary-key should be App-domain. As this should exist once at max. How should I fix what you suggest?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka you're right. edited

Comment: I downloaded your model yesterday and noticed that IsWhiteListed and Domain and AppId all had the little key icon, seeming to indicate to me that they were all set to be the primary key. If you open up the designer, and select those parts of your entities and see if in the Properties window there is anything to do with entity key you can disable on them.

Comment: @RobG "there is anything to do with entity key you can disable on them". What do you mean by `entity key`? how should I know if I could disable one of them?

Comment: @RobG can you please explain the error?

Answer (score 31):

I know this was a LONG time ago, but it is still showing up on search engines, so here's the deal.

The 3002 error indicates that there's a mismatch between the model and the actual database as to the primary key for a table. For example, the database may have only a single ID field as the primary key, but in the model it has two or more columns marked as part of the primary key. When I had this error, the model had marked all the non-null, foreign key fields as part of the primary key, which was not correct.

To fix, go into the model, locate the table, highlight every field that is erroneously marked as being part of the primary key, and change the "Entity Key" property to false. Recompile, and the error should be gone.

This worked for me.

Comment: This was my issue. Although I couldn't see anything wrong within the Model, I had to remove the entries from the .edmx itself. Thank you.

Comment: It appears that if your DB column ends in "ID", EF thinks it's a key.

Comment: @Efrain, in my case EF thought that columns ending with "Number" were also keys (in addition to ID column)..

Comment: I solved the issue by deleting the offending entity from the EDMX and re-adding it. Closing Visual Studio may have also helped because it crashed in between steps.